# Why is LAMPP making a copy of every single file in the project folder, as " ._. " format, ( e.g., ._.index.php) when moving the folder to vsc?

Tags: php, directory, format, xampp, lampp

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwimF.png)
Hi all!
I am using OS X, xampp for localhost, when I mount the volume lampp where htdocs is and bring one project folder to vsc it makes a copy of every single file in the folder in this format ._.   e.g.   `._.index.php`

If I open the project folder in vsc from different directory than htdocs from xampp/lampp these files do not exist.

Any idea on how to get rid of this files while using lampp?

Comment: Why do you delete them if those files are not in the folder? Also: How do you delete a file that does not exist? Please elaborate.

Comment: They look like backup copies. First, try to figure out if Code is to blame here. Create a new file with another editor, see if you get a copy. Open Code, see if you get a copy. Edit the file in code, see if you get a copy. Second, double-check there's no real file (dot files are often hidden by default in file managers). Third, determine what extension can be blamed with [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).

Comment: Are you using OS X? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: thanks for your answer @ÁlvaroGonzález , I will check out what you are saying.. I forgot to mention that when I create a new file inside the already opened folder, it does not create a copy, and yes I´m using OS X

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I noticed that the problem comes  when I bring the folder to visual studio code from Xampp on my OS X. Xampp is installed in my applications folder but apple does not recognize the app so I gotta give permission every time I use it,  when I mount the volume to find the folder htdocs where the projects are found, lampp opens as an external volume, and by the links you sent me before I believe that´s why this is happening I guess..  the point is that there must be a way to avoid seeing this in every folder I open with xampp :(

Comment: @hakre I tried to delete them to see if any changes basically, they are not hidden files, but they show up when I open them from the lampp volume as I explained in the above message..

Comment: @PabloVaró: Perhaps consider to [edit] your question as at least to me it was not clear from your question that the files do actually exist on disk. Also not that you're using and operating system by [Apple Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.). I'm currently under the impression that this is a feature of your operating system. I'd therefore suggest you consult dedicated support resources for your operating system to learn about that feature and that you understand the consequences when you delete  such files. I'm leaning towards to close as off-topic for SO atm.

Comment: you're welcome. you write you "mount lampp" - I can imagine it is of benefit to make this part more detailed: what is the source of mount and what is the target (at which place do you mount it in your file-system). I'd format such paths as a code-block so that one can quickly see and understand it. Not an XMPP pro, but I was under the impression that it just worked on the same file-system, so I would not even understand why there is a mount at all. Just you can better understand my perspective.